# Series - Landau notations

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's say I have $u_n = f(n) > 0$, such that $f(n) \sim g(n)$ and such that there exist $\alpha \geq 1$ such that : $g(n) = o(1/n^\alpha)$, then can I say that the series of general term : $u_n$ converges ?

For example if : $u_n = \frac{n^4\ln(3n)}{e^{2n}}$ then can I say the following :

$u_n \sim \frac{n^4\ln(n)}{e^{2n}}$ and because $\frac{n^4\ln(n)}{e^{2n}} = o(1/n)$ then $\sum u_n$ converges ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your general question, the *Bertrand's series*:
$$\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac1{n\log  n} $$
is a counter-example (by the integral test). If you have $\alpha>1$, you can  answer positively.

Comment: are you sure we must have $n>1$?

Comment: @gimusi: if the  second factor is $\log n$, yes. More precisely, if $\alpha =1$, the series $\;\dfrac1{n\log^\beta n}$ will converge if and only if $\beta >1$ (by the integral test). Let me add the question is somewhat imprecise.

Comment: indeed I think that the condition stated in the OP with $\alpha > 1$ is a sufficient but not necessary condition to guarantee that $\sum u_n$ converges.

Comment: I agree with you. I didn't say it was a necessary  condition. Do you think my phrasing is unclear in this respect?

Comment: Maybe the "must have" could be a little bit misleading, isn't it?

Comment: You're right. I thought that as it ended  in ‘you can answer’, and not ‘for the assertion to be true’, it wasn't ambiguous. I've modified the last sentence accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can say that the series converges by [limit comparison test](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/limit_comparison.html) with $\sum \frac 1 {n^a}$ for $a>1$ since

$$\large{\frac{\frac{n^4\ln(n)}{e^{2n}}}{\frac 1 {n^a}}\to 0}$$

Note that in general by limit comparison test it suffices that $u_n \sim \frac1 {n^a}$ with $a>1$ for convergence but it is not necessary as for example for $u_n=\frac1{n\log^2 n}$.